# intel wi-fi 6 ax200 intermittent on 20.4

Tags: 20.04

backport-iwlwifi-dkms v  8324-0ubuntu1 driver seems to work intermittently, freezing every few seconds for up to 30 seconds at a time.

boggles the mind how nobody bothered to test the wifi driver from the world's largest hardware company, on the world's most popular pre-installed with ubuntu computer. Any solutions?

Comment: There are no 'Ubuntu computers' but there are tens of thousands of possible hardware combinations it does work with. On the 1st day of a new release, problems are  inevitable. Please help us help you by identifying your WiFi  hardware.  Please run _sudo lshw|grep -A15 'network\|Wireless' && sudo lspci -v_, highlight the results, copy w/ Ctrl-Shift-C , return here, do [edit], & paste the results in your question.so the facts are there; also, what;s the make & model part number (from the serial # sticker) of your PC? Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you.

Answer (score 1):

looks like simply uninstalling backport-iwlwifi-dkms might have fixed the issue. Apparently not required?

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I had the exact same issue with my dell precision 7740 and the Wi-Fi 6 AX200 network card after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Probably when I installed 18.04 awhile back, I must have installed the backport-iwlwifi-dkms driver because my network card was too new and not supported in the 5.0 kernel that came with 18.04 at the time. Uninstalling the driver as you mentioned (and then rebooting) fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I don't recall ever installing it myself. My Dell XPS 13 7390 Developer Edition came pre-installed with 18.04 from the factory, so maybe Dell installs backport-iwlwifi-dkms by default? It did get upgraded to the latest version in focal, but wifi only works for me with it removed. WIFI works *great* with it remove too...

Comment: @bmcgair does this mean that you upgraded your dell by removing the hardcoded version in apt, and after removing the backport package everything is working perfectly fine? I'm looking into upgrading mine that I just bought. 18 is quite old.